# How can I force a WPF TextBox to both fill the content space, but also NOT grow beyond the bounds of it's container?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create a simple user control which is used for displaying a descriptive message to the user.  The XAML definition that I have for this control is as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Console.WPF.DisplayMessageView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             ...
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="550"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <!--Converters-->
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,5,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox 
            Grid.Column="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            FontWeight="Normal" 
            FontSize="10"
            Padding="12,4,2,2"
            Height="74" 
            Background="White"
            BorderThickness="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="{Binding DetailsText, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <Image Source="..." 
            Stretch="None" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,2,0,0"
            Visibility="{Binding IsErrorMessage, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This UserControl is currently embedded within a sizable stack of containers (DockPanels, StackPanels, etc.) and user controls.  However, it's first parent container is a DockPanel.  It is the last control in the DockPanel and the `LastChildFill` property is set to true on the panel.

My problem is that when I use this user control, regardless of HorizontalAlignment settings, it alway sizes the user control to the size of the text field.  This means that if the text field is short, the user control will be small and look odd since it's not filling it's respective content hole.  If the text is a vary long block of descriptive text, it doesn't wrap and continues to expand and is hidden off the edge of the screen.

I can't figure out how to fix this.  I also want to note that this application does not use scroll bars, which have been band from use, except on list boxes. I can't use scroll regions for this application, however, this message object absolutely must expand to fill the container but NOT expand any larger.

How can I accomplish this without constraining a fixed Width value on my user control instance?  Instead, I need the user control to grow with the container, when the window grows as well.

**NOTE**

I'm adding the C# tag, just in case this has to involve a code-behind change.  I really hope it's just a matter of setting the right set of magic-properties, which have eluded me, however, I'm not opposed to encoding a rock-solid code behind solution, so long as it specifically does what I need it to do.

Comment: Have you used the "[Live Visual Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)" debugging tool to help track down which container is causing the problem?  It's great for examining the tree and tweaking properties, while the application is running, to narrow down layout problems like this.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not in the UserControl, but in the Stack of parent controls. You can either use the Live Visual Tree, as Bradley already suggested, or sometimes coloring the background of controls also helps (just temporary with some bright colors, so you can see the space used by the control)

Comment: It would help if your question included the hierarchy of parent controls.  Is one of the parents a StackPanel with Horizontal orientation?  A StackPanel will never fill the remaining space in the direction of its orientation.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, numerous times.

Comment: @Spongebrot Oh yes, I'm well aware of the "let's color the background Magenta" technique.  Ugly colors FTW!

Comment: @RogerN I'll double check, but I don't think so.  I probably am using a StackPanel somewhere in the hierarchy, but in context, it's almost certainly set to vertical orientation.

Comment: @RogerN This was the answer, regarding the StackPanel.  Waaaaaaaay up the parent tree was, in fact, a StackPanel set to horizontal orientation.  Is there a way around this? From time to time, horizontal orientation within a StackPanel is needed.

Comment: No, I don't know of any way to force a StackPanel to use the remaining space.  I generally swap them out for a Grid or a DockPanel.  The other alternative is to write code-behind to dynamically set the width of one of the child controls.  That option feels ugly, though.

Comment: Problem for the StackPanel is, that is does not know which child should take up the remaining space. if its always the last one, try to add a grid with 2 columns and add the stackpanel to first column and the filling control to the second column.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Spongebrot.  In my case, the existence of the parent StackPanel was an artifact of some layout work. (I removed a fellow control, so the object within the SP was a sole control.) In my case, there was no harm removing the SP. If I need one, though, I'll try to grid technique.